# how to get single record in spring data JPA without using native query

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a requirement to get the single record using spring data JPA without using native query

This is working but if i use JPQL and use fetch first 1 row only JPA is not able to recognize fetch  keyword and throwing the exception .

I there any alternate way to get the single record without using native query .Any help appreciated .

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults-int-

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MYSQL then use "limit 1" if you are using Oracle then use "where rownum =1" in the JPQL query you wrote, that should work.

Orelse you can do this way also.

```
Query query=entityManager.createNativeQuery(string sql);
query.getMaxResults(1);
```